# How to create user from LDAP local in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, rhel7

I am trying to update `/etc/passwd` file using Ansible.

When I search for the user in `/etc/passwd` I am not able to find it. But when I execute the command `id username` it shows output with UDI and GID etc.

So in order to update `/etc/passwd`, I used the `user` module in Ansible.

```yaml
- name: Ensure user is present
  user:
    name: abc
    uid: 1111
    group: 2222
    state: present
  register: os_bin_user_created
```

It shows tasks OK

```yaml
ok: [lxxxxxx33.xxxxxxxxx.com] => {
    "append": false, 
    "changed": false, 
    "comment": "abc", 
    "group": 2222, 
     ....
            "password": null, 
            "password_lock": null, 
            "remove": false, 
            "uid": "1111", 
            "update_password": "always"
        }
    }, 
    "move_home": false, 
    "name": "abc", 
    "shell": "/bin/ksh", 
    "state": "present", 
    "uid": 1111
}
```

But the `/etc/passwd` is still not updated.

How to fix this?

If I am trying with a new user `xyz`, where `id` command output states user doesn't exists, then this code works (i.e it updates the `/etc/passwd`).

Comment: What operating system do you use? On Linux [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html) module executes `useradd` command and it's possible that it isn't related to Ansible. Also, does this user exists in `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` files? I'd also double check that you inspect the file on the right node (`lxxxxxx33.xxxxxxxxx.com` in your example).

Comment: RHEL 7 is the OS, yes i am checking on the corect server

Comment: /etc/shadow and /etc/group also doesnt have anything for this user

Comment: Have you tried to run ansible in debug mode (`-vvvv`)? Do it produces something useful?

Comment: By the way, so weird things could be related to SELinux.

Comment: If your system is configured to use directory sources other than `/etc/passwd` (such as ldap, nis, etc), you would expect this behavior if the user `abc` exists in one of those other sources.

Comment: yes i have pasted the output with -vvvv above

Comment: If `getent passwd abc` returns an entry for your user, then this is not an Ansible problem but is entirely a system configuration issue.

Comment: Yeah ldap is configured.and all the servers has the same results. so is there any workaround to add the user in /etc/passwd file. I need this of installation of an agent where the installation script checks the user exists in /etc/paswd file

Comment: yes getent passwd returns something like abc:xxx:1111:2222:abc:/export/home/abc:/bin/ksh

Answer (score 0):

> *LDAP is configured ... so is there any workaround to add the user in `/etc/passwd` file? I need this of installation of an agent where the installation script checks the user exists in `/etc/paswd` file*

For such cases were the groups and users are already defined in external directory services but an local mapping is necessary, as well for non conform group names (i.e. containing a space character) one could use the following approach.

```yaml
- name: Create 'default group' locally in /etc/group
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/group"
    line: 'default group:x:1234:'
    state: present
```

It makes sure that the domain default group is available and which would be otherwise impossible to create in RHEL 7 and with OS tools.

```yaml
- name: Create 'default user' locally in /etc/passwd
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/passwd"
    line: 'default user:x:1234:1234::/home/default user:/bin/bash'
    state: present
```